# How to declare reference resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating ALB and listeners. Trying to attach **load_balancer_arn** in same module. Here is my code:

less modules/alb/alb.tf

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = var.customer_env
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = var.security_group_alb
  #  subnets            = aws_subnet.private.*.id
  subnets = var.public_subnets

  enable_deletion_protection = false

  tags = {
    Name = var.customer_env
    Environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener" {
  for_each = var.listeners
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
  port = each.value["listener_port"]
  protocol = each.value["listener_protocol"]
```

less main.tf

```
module "alb" {
  source             = "./modules/alb"
  vpc_id             = module.network.vpc_id
  security_group_alb = module.security.security_group_alb
  public_subnets     = module.network.public_subnets
  customer_env = local.customer_env
  env  = var.env
  listeners = var.public_alb_config.listeners
  listener_port     = 80
  listener_protocol = "HTTP"
  target_groups = local.public_alb_target_groups
}
```

when i run terraform plan, getting the following error.

```
 terraform plan -var-file="env.tfvars"
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on modules/alb/alb.tf line 45, in resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener"                                                      :
│   45:   load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
│
│ A managed resource "aws_alb" "alb" has not been declared in module.alb.
╵
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `aws_lb.alb.arn`, not `aws_alb.alb.arn`.